# Proves, if possible, that the ideal is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Is it prime the ideal $\langle xy,zw\rangle$ in $k[x,y,z,w]$?

I am solving a Commutative Algebra exercise that asks you to calculate the radical of a certain ideal. By the calculations that made the candidate to radical is the ideal $\langle xy,zw\rangle$. I could not prove that is prime.

Comment: We have $xy\in I$, but is $x\in I$ or $y\in I$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ideal $I = \langle xy, zw \rangle$ is not prime, since $x \notin I, y \notin I$, but $xy \in I$.